# How to add SBT Plugin to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, sbt

I am trying to add SBT plugin to eclipse. I found github project but documentation doesn't seems to cover step by step process. I also tried to search any youtube video that explains the step by step process. Please mark all the step by step process to add sbt plugin in eclipse. I have already added scala-ide in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) is not a plug-in for Eclipse, it's a plug-in for SBT that generates Eclipse project files. Thus, you don't install it into Eclipse, you [install it into sbt](http://bfy.tw/2fD7).

Comment: E-Riz thanks for quick response. Can you specify what steps I need to perform? I have my project in eclipse.

Comment: E-Riz I am new to scala and SBT. I would appreciate if you can help me by giving the step by step process on how to use it.